# Angular - Button disabled if input is empty not working

Tags: angular

I have inputs like this:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let d of data">
    <mat-label>Item</mat-label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="d.item" matInput required>
</mat-form-field>`
```

I have tried this:

```
 <form #inputForm="ngForm">
        <mat-form-field *ngFor="let d of data">
            <mat-label>Item</mat-label>
            <input [name]="d.item" [(ngModel)]="d.item" matInput required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form> 

<button class="confirmButton" [disabled]="!inputForm.valid" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data">Send</button>
```

but when I type something just in one of inputs button is enabled, any soultion to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use reactive forms for dynamically created forms.

> Reactive forms provide a model-driven approach to handling form inputs whose values change over time. This guide shows you how to create and update a basic form control, progress to using multiple controls in a group, validate form values, and create dynamic forms where you can add or remove controls at run time.

See [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0):

In your html:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>
    Required Field:
    <input type="text" formControlName="requiredField" required>
  </label>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!testForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in your component:

```
  testForm = this.fb.group({
    requiredField: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

Comment: Because I still haven't read anything about reactive forms, can u tell me how should I populate that requiredField in loop?

Comment: This is a similar question to this one, I think.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094435/what-is-the-proper-way-to-dynamically-mark-a-field-as-required-using-angular-2-f)